# Mac OSX users on ZyWall USG 50 Network cannot connect to XMPP clients

Tags: mac-osx, xmpp, zyxel, zywall

No XMPP service will work on our ZyXEL ZyWall USG 50. We primarily use HipChat for communication, so when I try to telnet the server and port, I get an error:

```
> telnet chat-main.hipchat.com 5222
nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Every instance of Windows, regardless of laptop type, are working perfectly. Also, hardwired and wireless connections have the same results.

1. Is there any way to test generic XMPP ports or find out what the issue is exactly?
2. For anyone familiar with ZyWall routers, how can I test enabling/port-forwarding XMPP ports *very* safely?
3. How can I tell if the port is actually being blocked?
4. What would cause something like a specific port to be blocked only on Mac OS X?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"nodename nor servname provided, or not known" is a DNS resolution error.  Verify that your Macs are using the same DNS as their Windows brethren, and that there isn't something wonky in /etc/hosts circumventing proper DNS resolution.